# put an if to change a value if cursor value is null

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this cursor (SQL SERVER 2008 R2) to find out each product is in which category. but there is a problem which some products does not have any subcategory and also category(Product can join with subcategory and saubcategory can join with category). so all products are not in a category. I want to some how put an IF/ELSE statement in this cursor so if Production.ProductCategory = null so it will put it in another category which is 'No category !'
Any idea how ??

```
--** Force to use advantureworks
USE AdventureWorks
GO

--** Declaring Category Cursor variables
--** catName is for the CATEGORY NAME and count is a counter to count the row of output
DECLARE @catName VARCHAR(20), @count int

--** Declaring Category Cursor it self(to loop on categiries) and the SELECT statement
DECLARE catCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Production.ProductCategory.Name FROM Production.ProductCategory

--** Opening cursor and fetching data from it
OPEN catCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM  catCursor INTO @catName

--** Starting the loop in curser and filling the data
SET @count = 1
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN


PRINT N'Category Name: ' + CAST(@catName AS NVARCHAR) 
PRINT N'Description: No description'
PRINT N'Product List: '
PRINT N'Row NO.  Product ID     Product   Name                                  Unit Price($)   Is Top 10'
PRINT '======   ==========      =====================           ==========      ========='

--** Second cursor for products start here
--** Declaring Product Cursor variables
--** prodID, prodName and prodUnitPrice are what assignment wants from us
DECLARE @prodID INT, @prodName VARCHAR(30), @prodUnitPrice VARCHAR(20), @isTopTen VARCHAR (3)

--** Declaring Product Cursor it self(to loop on all products) and the SELECT statement
DECLARE prodCursor CURSOR FOR

--** HERE THERE MIGHT BE A CORRET SELEC STATEMENT WHICH STILL I DON'T KNOW WHAT IS !!!
--** I'VE WRITTEN SOMETHING WHICH IS NOT CORRECT BUT I PUT IT HERE IN COMMENTS:

SELECT DISTINCT A.ProductID, A.Name,  SUM(ISNULL(SOD.UnitPrice,0))/COUNT(*) 'Unit Price' , A.InTopTen 
FROM 
(SELECT P.ProductID, P.Name,PC.Name catName,
CASE WHEN X.ProductID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS InTopTen
FROM Production.Product P 
LEFT JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory PSC ON P.ProductSubcategoryID = PSC.ProductSubcategoryID
LEFT JOIN Production.ProductCategory PC ON PSC.ProductCategoryID = PC.ProductCategoryID
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 10 ProductID FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
        GROUP BY ProductID
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) X
ON X.ProductID = P.ProductID) A LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON A.ProductID = SOD.ProductID
WHERE A.catName = CAST(@catName AS NVARCHAR)
GROUP BY A.ProductID , A.Name, A.InTopTen
ORDER BY A.ProductID

--** Opening cursor and fetching data from it
OPEN prodCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM prodCursor INTO @prodID , @prodName , @prodUnitPrice , @isTopTen

--** Starting the loop in curser and filling the data
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
PRINT CAST(@count AS NVARCHAR) 
+'       '+ CAST(@prodID AS NVARCHAR)
+'          '+ CAST(@prodName AS NVARCHAR)
+'                  ' + CAST(@prodUnitPrice AS NVARCHAR)
+'          ' + CAST(@isTopTen AS NVARCHAR)
SET @count = @count+1

--** Fetching next data from product cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM prodCursor INTO @prodID , @prodName , @prodUnitPrice , @IsTopTen

--** End of product cursor
END
CLOSE prodCursor
DEALLOCATE prodCursor
--*******************               

PRINT '===================================================================================='

--** Fetching next data from category cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM catCursor INTO @catName

--** End of category cursor
END
CLOSE catCursor
DEALLOCATE catCursor

 --=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=* END OF QUERY =*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*
```

Comment: Currently are the products with no category in the result set but with catName `NULL`?

Comment: @OGHaza No they are not shown in result !
all products are 504 but this cursor return is only 295 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
DECLARE catCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Production.ProductCategory.Name FROM Production.ProductCategory
UNION ALL
SELECT 'No Category'
```

And then change your `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE ISNULL(A.catName, 'No Category') = CAST(@catName AS NVARCHAR)
```